# JQuery: A <select> in hover - Issues in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hover

I am having the more or less classic issue with a select dropdown not working properly in Internet Explorer 7+. It works worst in IE10. I am currently using a variant of a the timeout solution. However it does not work perfectly as you can see in this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CrLNU/175/

```
    $(document).ready( function() 
{
    var timer = 1;
    var layer;

    $('.image').mouseenter(function()
    {
        timer = clearTimeout(timer);
        layer = $(this);

        $(layer).children('.cities').stop(1).show();
        $(layer).children('select').show();
        $(layer).css('z-index', 1);
    }).mouseleave(function()
    {
        timer = setTimeout(function()
        {
            $(layer).children('.cities').hide();
            $(layer).css('z-index', 0);
            $(layer).children('select').hide();
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

UPDATE: In IE10 (and all Browser Modes below) the following happens: When I click the dropdown and then drag the mouse to select the second option the dropdown dissapears and the hover "flickers" like it has forgotten that I am in a hover div. If I increase the timeout the only thing that happens it take longer time for the dropdown to dissapear.

UPDATE 2: I added a lot more entries in the dropdown. Try and select the bottom one. Its very difficult.

After spending a whole day on this issue I would be very grateful for any tips or ideas for modifications that will make it work better.

Comment: What is the actual issue?  How is it not working properly?

Comment: It seems fine for me in IE9, what problem are you seeing?

Comment: Tested & working for me in IE8, 9, & 10.. although the child elements are not centered horizontally, they do appear and I am able to use the `<select>`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers. In IE10 (and all Browser Modes below) the following happens: When I click the dropdown and then drag the mouse to select the second option the dropdown dissapears and the hover "flickers" like it has forgotten that I am in a hover div.